# issues in uploading image on server folder

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I have the following code to upload images on server folder, but the issue is that it is giving format message even if i am uploading images of correct format
The error that i am getting is

```
 Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed
```

even if the images is of jpg/jpeg/png/gif format

The code that i am using is

```
<?php    
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
        {
            $target_dir = "profileimg/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
            if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
                {
                    if($check !== false) 
                        {
                            //echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                            $uploadOk = 1;
                        }
                    else 
                        {
                            echo "File is not an image.";
                            $uploadOk = 0;
                        }
                }

            // Check file size
            if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) 
                {
                    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }

            // Allow certain file formats
            if($imageFileType != "jpg" || $imageFileType != "png" || $imageFileType != "jpeg" || $imageFileType != "gif" ) 
                {
                    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }

            // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
            if ($uploadOk == 0) 
                {
                    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
                    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
                }
            else 
                {
                    $new_filename = $target_dir . uniqid() . '.' . $imageFileType;
                    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $new_filename))
                        {   
                            echo $new_filename;

                        }
                }
        }
?>
    <form  role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="input01" name="fileToUpload" 
        <button>Submit Form</button>
    </form>
```

can anyone plz correct the code

Comment: @Diddle Dot still getting the same error

Comment: `print_r($imageFileType)` to see what's in the variable

Comment: @Diddle Dot i not getting value in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form tag needs `enctype="multipart/form-data">` to upload file

SO change

```
<form  role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
```

TO

```
 <form  role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Otherwise your `$_FILES` variable is empty

ANd change you validation to

```
$allowed = array('gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');
$filename = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Comment: i added enctype but still the problem is same

Answer (score 1):

```
Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed
```

**you only check for jpg and all but not for JPG or Jpg**

check what kind of extantion have of your file.
put

```
 strtolower($imageFileType)
```